# Spring with Bukkit/Paper: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, minecraft, bukkit

I tried to run Spring Boot within my Java Plugin, but when I try to actually run it on the Server, it keeps producing this error:
The error is, that im am trying to load spring boot inside a paper environment and even when the spring.factories **is** included in my jar, it cannot be found in the minecraft server environment

```
[21:59:15 INFO]: [STDOUT]   .   ____          _            __ _ _
[21:59:15 INFO]: [STDOUT]  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
[21:59:15 INFO]: [STDOUT] ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
[21:59:15 INFO]: [STDOUT]  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
[21:59:15 INFO]: [STDOUT]   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
[21:59:15 INFO]: [STDOUT]  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[21:59:15 INFO]: [STDOUT]  :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.2)
[21:59:15 INFO]: 
[21:59:15 INFO]: Starting application using Java 17.0.2 on DESKTOP-N582J7M with PID 2364 (started by Programmers PC in F:\programming\paper 1.18.2 server)
[21:59:15 INFO]: No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
[21:59:15 ERROR]: Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories nor in META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:470) ~[paradubschmanager-0.1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.getCandidateConfigurations(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:185) ~[paradubschmanager-0.1.jar:?]
... 
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:164) ~[paradubschmanager-0.1.jar:?]
    at de.paradubsch.paradubschmanager.persistance.SpringConfigurer.initializeSpringApplication(SpringConfigurer.java:35) ~[paradubschmanager-0.1.jar:?]
    at de.paradubsch.paradubschmanager.ParadubschManager.onEnable(ParadubschManager.java:68) ~[paradubschmanager-0.1.jar:?]
...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
```

I'm using Spring v2.7.2, 
Paper git-Paper-260 (MC: 1.18.2) (Implementing API version 1.18.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT) (Git: bc68ee0)

To include this in my Plugin, I need it to work without parent. Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    ...
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Not Working idk why
                            <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar> -->
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                            <createSourcesJar>false</createSourcesJar>
                            <createTestSourcesJar>false</createTestSourcesJar>
                            <!--<transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers> -->

                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.kotlin_module</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.txt</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/proguard/*</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/services/*</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/versions/9/*</exclude>
                                        <exclude>*License*</exclude>
                                        <exclude>*LICENSE*</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <id>server</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <!-- This deletes all generated classes after the compilation.
                                 IDK why, but there are bugs if I don't do that-->
                                <exec dir="${project.basedir}/target/" executable="cmd.exe">
                                    <arg value="/c" />
                                    <arg value="@RD" />
                                    <arg value="/S" />
                                    <arg value="/Q" />
                                    <arg value='"./classes"' />
                                </exec>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!--<plugin>

                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M7</version>

                <configuration>
                    <junitArtifactName>org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter</junitArtifactName>
                    <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                </configuration>
            </plugin> -->
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>papermc-repo</id>
            <url>https://papermc.io/repo/repository/maven-public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
        ...
        <repository>
            <id>dmulloy2-repo</id>
            <url>https://repo.dmulloy2.net/repository/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Provided -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.papermc.paper</groupId>
            <artifactId>paper-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
       ...

        <!-- Runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jcache</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.seeseemelk</groupId>
            <artifactId>MockBukkit-v1.18</artifactId>
            <version>2.85.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I think i actually need the maven-compiler-plugin and maven-shade-plugin to properly bundle it for production.

My Main Method: src/main/java/de/paradubsch/paradubschmanager/ParadubschManager.java,

```
...
public class ParadubschManager extends JavaPlugin {
...
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
    ...
        ResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        ctx = SpringConfigurer.initializeSpringApplication(loader);
        ...
    }
}
```

calls my SpringConfigurer:

```
public static ConfigurableApplicationContext initializeSpringApplication(ResourceLoader loader) {
    return new SpringApplicationBuilder(SpringApplication.class).properties(getConfiguration()).run();
}
```

with properties getConfiguration(), to replace application.properties:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("spring.datasource.driver-class-name", ConfigurationManager.getString("hibernate.driver"));
props.put("spring.datasource.username", ConfigurationManager.getString("hibernate.user"));
props.put("spring.datasource.password", ConfigurationManager.getString("hibernate.pass"));
props.put("spring.datasource.url", ConfigurationManager.getString("hibernate.url"));
props.put("spring.jpa.show-sql", ConfigurationManager.getString("hibernate.showSql"));
props.put("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto", ConfigurationManager.getString("hibernate.hmb2ddlAuto"));
props.put("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect", ConfigurationManager.getString("hibernate.dialect"));
props.put("spring.flyway.enabled", "false");
props.put("logging.level.org.springframework", "DEBUG");
```

and starting my src/main/java/de/paradubsch/paradubschmanager/persistance/SpringApplication.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringApplication {
}
```

**I'm pretty sure the compilation works as intended:**
It compiles, shades and gives me my Jar
I doublechecked - my jar includes a META-INF/spring.factorys that is not empty, also the META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports.

So it has something to do with the ClassLoader not loading the file from my jar correctly.

I confirmed this when Mocking my Server with MockBukkit:

```
@BeforeAll
public static void setUp() {
    server = MockBukkit.mock();
    plugin = MockBukkit.load(ParadubschManager.class);
    server.getScheduler().performOneTick();
    server.getScheduler().waitAsyncTasksFinished();
    server.getScheduler().waitAsyncEventsFinished();
    adminPlayer = server.addPlayer();
    targetPlayer = server.addPlayer();
    server.getScheduler().waitAsyncTasksFinished();
    server.getScheduler().waitAsyncEventsFinished();
}
```

and then everything works as intended and all my tests pass.
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Unfortunately not, because unlike the other errors I've found I have no problem with my compilation pom.xml stuff, but with the execution/startup of my Spring Boot application or the class/ressource loading in the environment of a minecraft server.